# Smooth convolution in CUDA C++

Tags: cuda

I'm new at CUDA and I'm trying to implement smooth convolution on an image and so far I have this, but the result is wrong.
not sure if I did the offset movement correct. Any help?

```
__global__ void smooth(unsigned char* device_out_image, float kernel_size, unsigned char* device_input_imag, int height, int width)
{
    int pos_x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;//x coordinate of pixel
    int pos_y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;//y coordinate of pixel

    if (pos_x < width && pos_y < height)
    {
        unsigned char r = device_input_imag[pos_y * width + pos_x];//absolute pixel position
        unsigned char g = device_input_imag[(height + pos_y) * width + pos_x];
        unsigned char b = device_input_imag[(height * 2 + pos_y) * width + pos_x];
        //also mix value with the intensity instead of the range x
        float sumR = float(0.0f);
        float sumG = float(0.0f);
        float sumB = float(0.0f);
        for (int i = (-1 * 15); i <= 15; i++)
            for (int j = (-1 *15); j <= 15; j++)
            {
                if (pos_x + j > 0 && pos_y + i > 0 && pos_x + j <= width && pos_y + i <= height)
                {
                    sumR += (float)device_input_imag[(pos_y + i) * width + (pos_x + j)]/255.0;
                    sumG += (float)device_input_imag[(height + (pos_y + i)) * width + (pos_x + j)]/255.0;
                    sumB += (float)device_input_imag[(height * 2 + (pos_y + i)) * width + (pos_x + j)]/255.0;
                }   
            }
        sumR = sumR / (15 * 15);
        sumG = sumG / (15 * 15);
        sumB = sumB / (15 * 15);
        device_out_image[pos_y * width + pos_x] = (unsigned char)(sumR * 255.0);
        device_out_image[(height + pos_y) * width + pos_x] = (unsigned char)(sumG * 255.0) ;
        device_out_image[(height * 2 + pos_y) * width + pos_x] = (unsigned char)(sumB *255.0 );
        if (device_out_image[pos_y * width + pos_x] > 255)
            device_out_image[pos_y * width + pos_x] = 255;
        if (device_out_image[(height + pos_y) * width + pos_x] > 255)
            device_out_image[(height + pos_y) * width + pos_x] = 255;
        if (device_out_image[(height * 2 + pos_y) * width + pos_x] > 255)
            device_out_image[(height * 2 + pos_y) * width + pos_x] = 255;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to be more clear to explain your problem. You may re-edit your question.

Comment: Your loops go from -15 to 15, so you have 31*31 values: check the upper bound condition <=width mentioned by Peter. And an unsigned char value is never greater than 255. The average should not be either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following debug steps:

Can you set the output image to a gray ramp, where all 3 channels are the same, and the value is the x coordinate?  How about y?  This verifies that your output image interpretation, memcpy, channel layout, sizes, etc. are all correct.  If it is not correct, keep digging, and use the appearance of the result to help diagnose any issues.  For example, if you see a ramp effect, but it's misaligned, you probably have a wrong row spacing.  If the result isn't gray, you misunderstand where r, g, and b are located.  Back up a step and set only one channel at a time.

Can you copy the input image to the output image using the same kernel framework you have?  That is, comment out the loop and just set the output value to the input value.  This verifies that the input interpretation, memcpy, etc. is correct.

Move on to a kernel of size 3x3.  Then back to the whole thing.

A few other tips:

You should not need a float accumulator.  Since the image is made of 8-bit values, you will never overflow a 32-bit integer accumulator, even with much larger kernels (32 * 32 * 256 is 18 bits).

Review your > vs >= carefully.  0 is ok, so you want to test `idx>=0`, but width is not ok, so you need to test `idx<=width-1` or, more idiomatically, `idx<width`.

Do your output range clamping before assigning to the memory location. The optimizer will almost certainly fix this, but your code will also look simpler and be easier to verify if you clamp the temporary sumR/sumG/sumB values.